# Why are my cookies SO sticky?

Tags: cookies

So I've baked some apples just yesterday, and today they are extremely sticky.
Not because of the glaze or anything, it's just that they're sticky to the touch. I didn't add a lot of sugar, so I wonder, why would it appear like this? It just seems very annoying, because if I pack it into a box or something, it will stick to it and is inconvenient to me.

I only used 3/4 of a cup of brown sugar.
Also, my glaze starts to melt, even though its freezing cold here.

Comment: Your title says cookies and the question says apples.  What, exactly, did you bake, and could you provide more details please? :-)

Comment: Yeah, and what glaze exactly?

Comment: Please include the recipes you used—its hard to troubleshoot without them.

Comment: The question is internally inconsistent and so not answerable currently. It can get reopened if you edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* mean apples, and not cookies, which is what I'm assuming based off of your reference to glaze, the most likely culprit is the acidity in the apples. Adding an acidic substance to a sugar-based one (like brown sugar glaze) will cause the resulting mixture to be gummy and sticky. Without some more information about the type of apples and the process used in making them, I can't be more specific.

And of course, if your question is really about cookies, than this isn't an answer at all.